# File input not picking up copied or moved files Logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I'm successfully using logstash to parse json formated events and send them to elasticsearch. Each event is created in a seprate file. One event per file with .json extension.

Logstash is correctly picking up a file when i create it using "vi mydoc.json", paste in the content and save. However it does not pick up if I cp or mv a file.

The objective is to automatically copy files to a directory and then parse them by logstash.
Each file has a different name and size. I tried looking at logstash code to figure out what attribute it uses but couldnt find relevant code. I also tried deleting the .sincedb files but didn't help either.

The input config is as follows:

```
input {
file {
path => "/opt/rp/*.json"
type => "tp"
start_position => "beginning"
stat_interval => 1

  }

}
```

How can I have logstash pick up copied files? What file stat attribute does it use to check if a file is new?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can switch from Logstash to [Apache Flume](https://flume.apache.org): Flume has a [Spooling-Directory-Source](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#spooling-directory-source) (Logstash's input {}) and a [Elasticsearch-Sink](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#elasticsearchsink) (Logstash's output {}).
The Spooling-Directory-Source is exactly what you are looking for, afaics.

If you don't want to rewrite your Logstash-filter{} you can use Flume to collect the files and sink them into one file (see [File-Roll-Sink](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#file-roll-sink)) and let Logstash consume the events from it.

Be aware, that the file operations in Flume's spooling dir have to be atomic. Don't change a processed file or append to it.